# SSRS Visual Studio 2008 - How to compare name to pipe delimited list of names?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, where-clause

I am fairly new to sql. I am trying to get a count of activities done by specified people in a persons table.

Pseudo sql query:

```
select count
from activities table a 
left outer join persons table p
where p.lastName + ', ' + p.firstName like 'LastName1, FirstName1 | LastName2, FirstName2 |..."
```

What is a good way to compare the names in the persons table to a pipe delimited list of names passed as a parameter in an SSRS report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

Total of activities for persons of interest

```
SELECT COUNT(*) activities_count
  FROM activites a LEFT JOIN
       persons p ON a.person_id = p.id
 WHERE 'Lee, Mark | Doe, Jhon' LIKE '%' + p.lastName + ', ' + p.firstName + '%'
```

Number of activities per person

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(*) activities_count
  FROM activites a LEFT JOIN
       persons p ON a.person_id = p.id
 WHERE 'Lee, Mark | Doe, Jhon' LIKE '%' + p.lastName + ', ' + p.firstName + '%'
 GROUP BY p.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f4e/4)**